# How to rewrite a domain to another one in IIS 10?

Tags: iis

I have the following website configuration on IIS 10.

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rule1">
                  <match url=".*" />                     
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.google.com/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>            
    </rewrite>
```

I'm trying to rewrite all the requests sent to mydomain.com to google.com (taken as an example)

When running the website, I'm getting the following google error page in the screenshot. Means the rewrite is not behaving properly and doesn't send requests to the domain "www.google.com".

[image]

What can I try to solve this?

Comment: That's expected, as many sites do not like to be rewritten to. If you use another site, it might work as you desired.

Comment: @Lex Li I tried another website that belongs to me but it's not working neither. Do you have any other idea please ? Thanks

Comment: Can you check Mistake 3 in https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59?

Comment: Try clearing the cache and try again, if that doesn't work, I suggest you use failed request tracing to see if you can get useful information.